# How to: Power Automate auto resizes images match a condition

Tags: images, microsoft-power-automate-desktop

- I am newbie to **Microsoft Power Automate**. I want to **batch resize images** (in a directory) meet a condition but don't know how to do that.
- I did: sort images by size. Then record actions: right click on the first item, open with MS Paint, resize to 50%, save, close.
- Problem: **Power Automate** only finds the exact file of my last action, it doesn't find the first file after sorting.
  [image]
- I also want add a condition: only resize image larger than (1200x2100) or (2100x1200).
- How to I do batch resize images (in a directory) and meet the condition?
  Thank you very much!